# How do fit image into its container using flexbox?

Tags: html, css

```
.navbar{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%;   
}
.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.navbar a {
  float:right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 30px 30px;
}

body{
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#intro{
  padding-top:50px;
text-align:center;
}

#email-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}

#video{
  text-align:center;
}

#email-input{
  width:348px;
}

#email-submit{
  background-color:#4CAF50;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  color:white;
  margin:10px 14px;
  border-radius:4px;
}

#features2{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-basis:1em;
}
#clothes{
  height:200px;
  width:auto;
}
#credit-card{
  height:200px;
  width:auto;
}
#delivery-truck{
  height:300px;
  width:auto;
}



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <div class="navbar" id="navigationbar">
    <a href="#Features">Features</a>
    <a href="#intro">Introduction</a>
    <a href="#prices">Prices</a> <br><br><br>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
  <div id="intro">
    <h1 id="header">Company name</h1>
    <img id="header-image" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/circle-business-logo-company-name-260nw-626261534.jpg" alt="company-logo"><br><br>
  </div>
    
    
    <div id="email-container">
      <form>
        <div id="email">
        <input id="email-input" type="email" placeholder="Enter your E-mail here..."></div>
        <button id="email-submit"><b>SUBMIT E-MAIL TO RECEIVE LATEST NEWS</b></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  
  <div id="features">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <div id="features1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div id="features2">
      <img id="delivery-truck" src="https://wholesale-steroids.cc/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/delivery-truck-400x400.png" alt="delivery-truck">
      <img id="clothes" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/106/106020.png" alt="clothes">
      <img id="credit-card" src="https://loanssos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/credit-card.png" alt="credit-card">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="prices">
  </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

I want to put the images in a column, like vertically but it ended up being stretched and idk how to fix it. I used flex so I can arrange them and place them besides the Lorem ipsum words later on. Is there a better way that's easy? I'm kind of new to HTML and css. Sorry there's a lot of unnecessary code as I just copy pasted the whole thing, but you only need to look at the img-src and the css counterparts  think. EDIT:Thanks it has been solved :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [object-fit:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit#:%7E:text=The%20object%2Dfit%20CSS%20property,using%20the%20object%2Dposition%20property.) with `contain` CSS property to get original size of the image and fit it nicely.

> The `object-fit` CSS property sets how the content of a replaced element, such as an `img` or `video`, should be resized to fit its `container`.

**Live Demo**

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0;
  /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a {
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 30px 30px;
}

body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#intro {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#email-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#video {
  text-align: center;
}

#email-input {
  width: 348px;
}

#email-submit {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#features2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 1em;
}

#clothes {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#credit-card {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#delivery-truck {
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div class="navbar" id="navigationbar">
  <a href="#Features">Features</a>
  <a href="#intro">Introduction</a>
  <a href="#prices">Prices</a> <br><br><br>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="intro">
    <h1 id="header">Company name</h1>
    <img id="header-image" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/circle-business-logo-company-name-260nw-626261534.jpg" alt="company-logo"><br><br>
  </div>


  <div id="email-container">
    <form>
      <div id="email">
        <input id="email-input" type="email" placeholder="Enter your E-mail here..."></div>
      <button id="email-submit"><b>SUBMIT E-MAIL TO RECEIVE LATEST NEWS</b></button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="features">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <div id="features1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div id="features2">
      <img id="delivery-truck" src="https://wholesale-steroids.cc/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/delivery-truck-400x400.png" alt="delivery-truck">
      <img id="clothes" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/106/106020.png" alt="clothes">
      <img id="credit-card" src="https://loanssos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/credit-card.png" alt="credit-card">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="prices">
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the flex from your container  and I have placed in ccs that your images have a display: block and an auto margin.

```
.navbar{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%;   
}
.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.navbar a {
  float:right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 30px 30px;
}

body{
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#intro{
  padding-top:50px;
text-align:center;
}

#email-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}

#video{
  text-align:center;
}

#email-input{
  width:348px;
}

#email-submit{
  background-color:#4CAF50;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  color:white;
  margin:10px 14px;
  border-radius:4px;
}

#features2 img{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
#clothes{
  height:200px;
  width:auto;
}
#credit-card{
  height:200px;
  width:auto;
}
#delivery-truck{
  height:300px;
  width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding CSS `#features img { object-fit: contain; }` to use just one rule for all your images inside your flex box div.

Adding the `object-fit: contain;` CSS attribute to your images and it will preserve your images aspect ratio.

For this property you can use whatever fits the most for what you're looking for, more options are available for object-fit, like cover, fill or scale-down.

You can test them and see if fits your needs!